# Data values greater than float capacity - plotting in Octave

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I have a pretty simple octave script and I'm just trying to plot a few values but I'm getting the error:

```
warning: gl-render: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale data, or (2) Use gnuplot
```

The script is:

```
a = 0.2;
z = 160;
L = 8; 
w = 31.12;
x = 0;
g = 9.81;
k = 0.785;
rho = 1025;

  for t = 0:10
      eta_0 = -(1/g)*exp(0)*cos(k*x-w*t);
      u_x = a*w*exp(k*z)*cos(k*x-w*t);
      w_x = a*w*exp(k*z)*sin(k*x-w*t);
      p_d = -rho*a*g*exp(k*z)*cos(k*x-w*t);
  endfor

plot(t,eta_0); hold on
plot(t,u_x); hold on
plot(t, w_x); hold on
plot(t,p_d);
```

I can't find anything useful about this error after searching online and am new to using octave and gnuplot so not sure exactly how to use gnuplot instead. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Any advice or help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It works fine for me in Octave 3.8. Try `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')` at the command prompt to use gnuplot, then run the code again see if it works better.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want your loop to be as follows, otherwise, you'll only get a single data point, not a curve:

```
for t = 0:10
      eta_0(t) = -(1/g)*exp(0)*cos(k*x-w*t);
      u_x(t) = a*w*exp(k*z)*cos(k*x-w*t);
      w_x(t) = a*w*exp(k*z)*sin(k*x-w*t);
      p_d(t) = -rho*a*g*exp(k*z)*cos(k*x-w*t);
endfor
```

or even better (without the for loop, using vectorised operations):

```
t = 0:10;
eta_0 = -(1/g)*exp(0)*cos(k*x-w*t);
u_x = a*w*exp(k*z)*cos(k*x-w*t);
w_x = a*w*exp(k*z)*sin(k*x-w*t);
p_d = -rho*a*g*exp(k*z)*cos(k*x-w*t);
```

The values you are trying to plot are very large (~7e57), which is probably the source of the error. Try adding `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')` at the beginning of your code to use the `gnuplot` graphics toolkit and see if it works better. I tried it in octave 3.8 and it works fine, giving me the following plot:

[image]

Comment: PS: All the plots are not really visible on the graph because `p_d` is so huge, everything else looks essentially zero (even though it isn't). You probably need to scale your data if you want to see everything onto one plot.

Comment: that's really helpful, thanks. I did notice that I was only getting one data point as well so fixed that. will try your suggestion now

Comment: stupid question but when using gnuplot, is that the command instead of plot?

Comment: `gnuplot` is just a different graphics toolkit to use when rendering plots, you still issue the `plot` command as normal.